# ERROR:Message 279 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, event-listener, oracle19c

I have issue with LISTENER so I can't start listener with :

```
>lsnrctl status LISTENER

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-MAR-2022 16:07:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521)) TNS-12541: TNS:no listener  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error   TNS-00511: No listener    64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Same error with the lsnrctl reload

When I try to restart it from services windows I have the issue :services on local computer started and stopped
As mentioned in the Snape below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZTkc.png)

This is listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\instantclient_19_8\NETWORK\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER_UBIX =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ubix)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c)
      (SID_NAME = ubix2)
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER_UBIX = C:\app\e5665551

SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER_UBIX = TRUE

LISTENER_UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
  )
```

and the tnsnames file :

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.



ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = UBIX)
    )
  )
LISTENER_UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

and the log file:

```
LISTENER for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production 
Version 19.10.0.0.0

Message 459 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 279 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 510 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL

Message 1081 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
Message 1074 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
Message 1050 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

I ask if the problem with security update my block the service of listener ?

```
>sc.exe query OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C

SERVICE_NAME: OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I try to start it by the command line :

```
sc start OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C
```

also with killing the service

```
taskkill /pid 94196 /F
```

THE service still stuck on STOPPED it's the same issue please any help ?

Comment: please any help

Comment: Just as an aside, you posted the content of tnsnames.ora, but this file has zero, zilch, nada, null to do with the operation of the listener.  The listener is a process that runs on the database server.  tnsnames.ora is nothing but an address book used by _client_ processes.

Answer (score 1):

When you get such a plethora of error messages of the kind "Message not found" it normally means one of two things

- corrupted install
- environment variable issue

We're going to look at directories under the env var setting for ORACLE_HOME for messages and configuration etc.  Thus if you have set ORACLE_HOME incorrectly at (say) system level, or user level, then if we pick that setting up and then cannot find the message files under that path, then we're going to send out these kinds of errors.

So double check (a) your ORACLE_HOME if set, is set correctly and (b) your TNS_ADMIN if, is set correctly

Comment: I have reinstall and the problem of the listener solved